# Mysql with version higher than the project (C# WPF)

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, wpf

I picked up an old project to use my kinnect, but I need MySql for this application, so I tried to insert MySql.dll into this project, but I am getting this error.

> Gravidade Código  Descrição   Projeto Arquivo Linha   Estado de Supressão
> Aviso       Não foi possível resolver a referência primária "MySql.Data, Version=8.0.25.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d, processorArchitecture=MSIL" porque ela tem uma dependência indireta no assembly de estrutura "System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", que não pôde ser resolvida na estrutura de destino atual. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". Para resolver o problema, remova a referência "MySql.Data, Version=8.0.25.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d, processorArchitecture=MSIL" ou redirecione o aplicativo para uma versão de estrutura que contenha "System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". ShapeGame
>
> Gravidade Código  Descrição   Projeto Arquivo Linha   Estado de Supressão
> Aviso       A referência primária "MySql.Data, Version=8.0.25.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d, processorArchitecture=MSIL" não pôde ser resolvida porque foi compilada com base na estrutura ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2". Esta versão é superior à da estrutura de destino ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client".  ShapeGame

I can use MySql in this version of NET? I believe if I change other libraries does not work

Comment: try another connector and report it to oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be targeting the .NET 4.0 Client Profile. This is very old (over ten years), so for compatibility you'll also need to use a very old version of MySql.Data.

It looks like [MySql.Data 6.9.12](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/6.9.12) should be compatible with .NET 4.0, although it still may not work with the Client Profile. (The Client Profile is targeted at desktop client applications, but MySQL is typically used by server-side applications.)

If it doesn't work, try an even older version of MySql.Data.

If you want to use the latest MySql.Data, you will also need to use a much more recent version of the .NET Framework.